# JSDoc "includePattern" multiple file types

Tags: javascript, vue.js, jsdoc

I've just started to use JSDocs and am trying to apply it to my Vue.js project. As it consists of multiple file types (namely .js and .vue) I am trying to add them to my "includePattern", however I am getting a syntax error at the following:

```
"source": {
    "include": ["src"],
    "includePattern": "(.js|.vue$)",
    "excludePattern": "(node_modules/|docs)"
}
```

Really not sure how to work around it as the docs are confusing me a little on this issue.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Basicly I didnt do my propper research and there is a [specific plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsdoc-vuejs) for Vue.js and JSDoc to interact with each other.

to add another file you simply need to move the pipe to a differant spot and write it like this:

```
"includePattern": ".\\.(js|vue)$"
```